# Apache web server - what am I missing?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, dns, webserver

I am trying to set up an apache server v2.4.7 on Ubuntu 14.01. My domain name is thesalmonkiller.com and I have included it and the DNS that it points to (provided by GoDaddy's DNS Zone File) in /etc/hosts. Here is my virtual host configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
ServerName thesalmonkiller:80

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I also have thesalmonkiller.conf in my sites-enabled directory. But the site thesalmonkiller.com is still empty. And on the local computer, I see localhost displaying the index.html. Anyone know what I am missing?
Thanks

Comment: Close because it's off topic (about professional network infrastructure) or close because it doesn't give a single clue what the actual problem is...

Comment: use `ServerName thesalmonkiller.com` and check DocumentRoot is correct or not

Comment: @TamilSelvan the DocumentRoot is correct and ServerName doesn't fix it. Anything else?